# Pandas get all records which have the same ID in all dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of dataframes. Each dataframe has a column called `probe_id`.
I want to get all rows where the `probe_id` exists in all data frames. In other words, I want to find the intersection of the dataframes on `probe_id`.

For example, let's say I have 4 dataframes and each dataframe has the `probe_id '0001'`. In this case, I would return that row. If the `probe_id` is missing from any of the dataframes, I want to skip that row.

Also, since the values in the other columns of each dataframe might differ, I need to make sure this data is not lost.

So, if each of the 4 dataframes has 2 columns, the result should be a new dataframe  with 8 columns where the records `probe_id` exists in all 4 dataframes.

I am using:

`z = reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on='PROBE_ID', how='inner'), dataframes)`

It appears to work, but I am not sure and there are too many records to check. I am not entirely confident on using `reduce` and `lambda`, so I'd appreciate if someone could let me know if this is correct or not and if not, how I could achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `concat`, also if they share the common column , I think you can just restore it once, save same value multiple times is kind of redundant

```
df_out = pd.concat([
    x.set_index('dataframes') for x in dataframes
], axis=1, join ='inner').reset_index()
```

Comment: Nice, looks like we have a similar idea to use the index!

Comment: But your answer is much better, I forgot about the `join='inner'` argument.

Comment: @coldspeed a ha , I think that is credit to Pir 's recent Q&A about the `concat `

Comment: Thanks! This seems to give the same answer as my proposed solution, so it looks like this is just another way to achieve my goal. Besides being more readable, could you kindly provide some reasons as to why your approach would or would not be preferred?